# Node.js createWriteStream 'finish' called late

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Function hosted on Firebase which takes an image URL from Twilio and, using `pipe()`, uploads the image to a bucket on GCS.  This works, however I want to call another function once the image has been successfully uploaded.  I have a `.on('finish')` to trigger another function, however in looking at logs, it appears the finish is being called almost a minute after the file has actually finished uploading.  I can physically see the image in my GCS console well before the finish function is called.

What might be the cause of this delay?

```
const mediaUrl    = request.body.MediaUrl0;
const contentType = request.body.MediaContentType0;
const extension   = mime.extension(contentType);
global.filename   = Date.now() + "." + extension;

console.log("Filename: " + filename);

//Save image to gcs bucket
const gc = new Storage({
  projectID: 'testProject-rgjdxr'
});

const bucketName = 'msg-images';
const bucket = gc.bucket(bucketName);
const file = bucket.file(filename);
const w = file.createWriteStream({
  metadata:{
    contentType: contentType
  }
});

pollRequest(mediaUrl).auth(accountSid, authToken).pipe(w).on('finish', () => {
  global.gcsUrl = `https://storage.cloud.google.com/${bucketName}/${filename}`;
  console.log(gcsUrl); 

//I can see this log, however the timestamp is about 60sec
//after the file was uploaded successfully to GCS bucket.

  analyzeImage(gcsUrl); //passing image url to another function
});
```

Comment: Even though the Cloud Storage is triggering a Cloud Functions but for other notifications mechanism for Cloud Storage, Pub/Sub notifications [1] and Object change notification [2] indicates there can be delay but it should trigger within seconds. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#delivery_guarantees
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery

Comment: To find out the root cause it may require more information like whether this happens just one time or all the time, whether the delay is always one minutes and more indepth investigation which is not possible here. 

If you consider this due to a technical issue, I would suggest to create a free case with Firebase Support:

[1] https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0